# Why does Google App Engine Search return only the "best" results?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

GAE [full text search](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview), 3 test data entries in the index:

name(1):test1
name(2):test1 test2
name(3):test1 test2 test3

query1: name:test1
result1: name(1), name(2), name(3)

query2: name:test1 test2
result2: name(2), name(3)

query3: name:test1 test2 test3
result3: name(3)

I would like to get back from all the 3 queries all the 3 entries (and sort them by relevancy). I've checked all the search.QueryOptions settings, but I couldn't reach the expected result.

At the moment I see constructing a query expression myself from the input as an only option (solution1: name: test1 OR test2 OR test3; solution2: name: test1 OR (test1 test2) OR (test2 test3) OR (test1 test3) OR (test1 test2 test3)) but it's simply hard to believe that it would be the proposed way to do it.

Python 2.5, tested with SDK and production as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not return those other results because they *do not match the query*. The default operation is an 'and' not an 'or' - as it should be for any sane search facility. Using or as a default in real world situations will return a great number of irrelevant results: when I search for 'app engine', I do not want to know about apps, or about engines.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your answer! As a google search user my experience is that it gives back not only those results what contains all the words what I gave as an input (I'm aware of there is stopword elimination and other input processes), they "just" ranked higher. I would like to give the same experience to my users. At first look and operation seems too strict to me.

Comment: @LászlóFarkas Google Search has a lot more data to work with, and a very tuned, very specific query engine. It's able to do things like include documents that are linked to with a specific word, look up synonyms of words, and other tricks to give high quality results. It rarely if ever simply discards a search term entirely and returns documents that only refer to part of your search. You're welcome to try, but please do compare your search with 'or' and 'and' - I think you'll find that using 'or' makes the quality of the search way lower, without adding any useful signal.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not completely clear to me but this query:

```
(name: test1 OR (test1 test2) OR (test1 OR test2 OR test3))
```

does not really make sense. this is all you need:

```
name:(test1 OR test2 OR test3)
```

from the query examples you listed i think what your missing is only the OR operator between the values in all 3 queries:

query1: `name:test1`
query2: `name:(test1 OR test2)`
query3: `name:(test1 OR test2 OR test3)`

and you will get all 3 documents back for all 3 queries.

Comment: Hi aschmid00, Thanks for your answer! You're right regarding the query, it's corrected now in the question. So you say the query has to be constructed by myself. Anyway "name: test1 OR (test1 test2) OR (test2 test3) OR (test1 test3) OR (test1 test2 test3)" and "name:test1 OR test2 OR test3" gives completely different sort_scores for the hits. In the first case difference is quite significant (0.64; 0.57; 0.36) in the second case sort_score it's almost the same (0.29; 0.28; 0.27). But this and the cost is an other question...